# Multiple domains mixed up with SSL configuration with Apache httpd

Tags: apache, ssl, dns

I have two domains and 1 IP address. In my httpd.conf file, I added,

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.domain1.com  
ServerAlias domain1.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain1.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.domain2.com 
ServerAlias domain2.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain2.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

There are some cases that domain2 URLs are redirected to domain1 (pay attention to the url protocols).

For example, on iPhone/Safari,
http://www.domain2.com
http://domain2.com
will both be redirected to https://www.domain1.com

On Windows using MSIE,
http://domain2.com
will both be redirected to https://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain2.com works fine.

On Windows using Chrome, most of the cases work except,
https://domain2.com will be considered insecure.

So this looks like a browser problem. Is there a way to prevent this from happening reliably?

Thanks.

Comment: This .conf file will not cause such mixup. There is something more here, either .htaccess, or other directives in .conf, or even apps running on those domains.

Comment: Can you be more specific what to look for? I didn't touch .htaccess file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (it works for me):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example1.com
  ServerAlias example1.com
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.:9090/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example2.com
  ServerAlias example2.com
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9091/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9091/
</VirtualHost>
```